# Leaflet.js client-syde screenshot whit support of translate 3d

Tags: canvas, svg, 3d, leaflet, hardware-acceleration

Good day!
I'm trying to generate screenshot of leaflet map with html rasterize.
Cause of usind translate3d and scale(hardware acceleration) libraries canvg and html2canvas can't give me good result.
Does anybody know what should I do to take html screenshot?
Firstly, as painting tiles - ok(but it is just lucky, because html2canvas take translate[0] as x, and translate[1] as y. If layer has got scale - it gave me wrong position)

May be there are scripts that works with this problems?

Comment: did you manage to generate the screenshot successfully with canvg and html2canvas?

Comment: Yes, step by step, each pane I draw on canvas with translate 3d offsets, but svg pane I push into canvg (NOT canvg.min.js, only canvg.js), draw it on another canvas, than offsets it with translate3d params.

Comment: Thanks. Can you post how you offset translate3d over canvas? my SVG drawn over canvas offset at wrong position, I'm on it thanks again

Comment: Look at answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is class method
map - is usual map,
mainpane - is  cloned map container,
ctx - is main canvas context:

```
    var mainpane = $(map.getContainer()).clone();
    var mapPane = mainpane.find(".leaflet-map-pane")[0];
    var mapTransform = mapPane.style.transform.split(",");
    this.mapX = parseFloat(mapTransform[0].split("(")[1].replace("px", ""));
    this.mapY = parseFloat(mapTransform[1].replace("px", ""));
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.className = "screenShotCanvas";
    canvas.width = map.getSize().x;
    canvas.height = map.getSize().y;
    canvas.style.left = -this.mapX;
    canvas.style.top = -this.mapY;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");



drawSVGOnCanvas: function(map, mainpane, ctx) {
    var overlayClass = $(map.getPanes().overlayPane).attr('class');
    var svgE = mainpane.find('.' + overlayClass.replace(' ', '.')).find('svg');
    var xml;
    var svgElements = svgE[0];
    var svgElementsTransform = svgElements.style.transform.split(",");
    var svgElementsX = parseFloat(svgElementsTransform[0].split("(")[1].replace("px", ""));
    var svgElementsY = parseFloat(svgElementsTransform[1].replace("px", ""));
    svgElements.style.transform = " ";
    svgElements.style.left = svgElementsX + "px";
    svgElements.style.top = svgElementsY + "px";

    var svgCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    svgCanvas.className = "screenShotTempCanvas";
    svgCanvas.id = "SvgToCanvas";
    svgCanvas.width = map.getSize().x;
    svgCanvas.height = map.getSize().y;
    var svgCtx = svgCanvas.getContext("2d");

    svgE.each(function() {
        L.DomUtil.getPosition(svgE);
        xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(this);
        canvg(svgCanvas, xml);
    });
    ctx.drawImage(svgCanvas, svgElementsX + that.mapX, svgElementsY + that.mapY);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Triple-B, I did something similar.

```
        var that  = this,
            map_c = that.map.getContainer();

        //Check if have svg on map
        var svg     =  map_c.querySelector('svg');
        var _canvas = map_c.querySelector('canvas');

        if(svg) {

            var svg_attr = {
                w: parseInt(svg.attributes.width.value),
                h: parseInt(svg.attributes.height.value)
            };

            _canvas.width  = svg_attr.w;
            _canvas.height = svg_attr.h;

            _canvas.style.display = 'block';

            var serializer = new XMLSerializer();

            var c   = _canvas;
            var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, svg_attr.w, svg_attr.h);

            var trans_val = map_c.querySelector('.leaflet-map-pane').style['transform'].replace('translate','').replace(/px/g,'').replace('(','').replace(')','').split(',');

            var trans_y = parseInt(trans_val[trans_val.length - 1]) ,
                trans_x = parseInt(trans_val[trans_val.length - 2]);


            ctx.translate(trans_x,trans_y);
            ctx.drawSvg("<svg>"+serializer.serializeToString(svg)+"</svg>", 0, 0, svg_attr.w, svg_attr.h);
            svg.style.display = 'none';
        }
```